# Import difference in CSV to Azure sec group

Tags: powershell, office365

I want to compare all shared mailboxes in Exchange online with members in a Azure sec group and import the difference in the Azure sec group. I believe it fails somewhere in the last 3 rows. It is for a backup solution and I am not the creator of the code.

Get-EXORecipient -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox" | select PrimarySMTPAddress | Export-Csv "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\Sharedmailboxes\sharedmailboxes.csv"

$GroupMembership = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "group id" -top 10000 | Select-Object @{Name="PrimarySMTPAddress";Expression={$_.userprincipalname}} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\Sharedmailboxes\Groupmembership.csv"

$File1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\Sharedmailboxes\sharedmailboxes.csv"

$File2 = (Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\Sharedmailboxes\Groupmembership.csv").PrimarySMTPAddress

$File1 | where-object{$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -notin $File2} | Export-csv -path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\sharedmailboxes\difference.csv"

$Diff = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\sharedmailboxes\difference.csv"

The file difference.csv is populated and formatted as
A
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
PrimarySmtpAddress
x@domain.com

$UserObjectId = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\sharedmailboxes\difference.csv" | ForEach-Object {get-azureaduser -searchstring $_.PrimarySmtpAddress}

$Userobjectid | select objectid | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\sharedmailboxes\userobjectid.csv"

The file userobjectid.csv is empty after above command :(

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\mnym\Downloads\sharedmailboxes\userobjectid.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "group id" -Refobjectid $_.objectid}

I tried to import the difference.csv but I can't seam to get the Refobjectid to match the CSV, I get "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'RefObjectId' because it is null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your file system as a variable registry - there's no need to write data to a CSV file only to read it straight back into memory :)

Your code could be as simple as:

```
# Define the target group id
$groupID = "group id"

# Start by creating a set of all email addresses that are already members of the security group
$securityGroupMembers = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupID -Top 10000 |ForEach-Object { 
    [void]$securityGroupMembers.Add($_.PrimarySMTPAddress)
}

# Then fetch the shared mailbox and check if they're already members of the group
Get-EXORecipient -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox" |ForEach-Object {
    if(-not $securityGroupMembers.Contains($_.PrimarySMTPAddress)){
        # Add shared mailbox to group
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupID -Refobjectid $_.ObjectId
    }
}
```

Comment: The code was to be used in a function so perhaps that's why the CSV part is in the code. I could not get the function to work so I got back to local PS to see if the code works. I now get "Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'RefObjectId' because it is null. At line:15 char:64" in your example. Some easy fix?

Comment: @Magnus I don't have access to an Exchange Online org to test, but I suspect `Get-EXORecipient` returns an object with an `ExternalDirectoryObjectID` property, so try `Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupID -RefObjectId $_.ExternalDirectoryObjectID` instead

Comment: $_.ExternalDirectoryObjectID worked fine thanks :) but I don't get why. Is it because it is listed as the first attribute?

Comment: @Magnus Why? Because the architects of Exchange Online decided to put the directory ID in a property called `ExternalDirectoryObjectID`, so that's what you need to reference - simple as that :)